# GridView items merged android

Tags: java, android, gridview

I'm creating a gridview that items come from database..

Every thing works well.. but when I try my app I see these merged items in the image below..

So the question is : What is the reason for this and how to fix it ?

[image]

This is my xml :

```
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:columnWidth="130dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
    </GridView>
```

and this is my grid item xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/round_rect"
android:padding="15dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/categoryIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/categoryName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your xml ? I'm guessing that the lower cube is too big, so it expands to the top, hence - you don't see the space between the items.

Comment: Done adding xml files..

Comment: Just for testing, try removing the padding on grid_item.xml (from the LinearLayout android:padding="15dp" and  android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" from the TextView), you don't have enough space for the content as declared, since you have 2 lines in the text

Answer (score 0):

I assume the issue is that every grid cell should have the same size.

since your item has

```
 <ImageView ...
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

a cell is as big as its image.

if you set it to some absolute size all cells should be the same

```
 <ImageView ...
  android:layout_width="100dp"
  android:layout_height="100dp" />
```

also make shure that the TextView uses only one line

```
  <TextView ...
    android:ellipsize="start"
    android:singleLine="true"
    ... />
```